# Understanding C arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

Need a little help understanding what exactly is going on in this code snippet.
When I run the program it prints 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int c = 5;
int *p = a;
printf("--> %d", (c[b])[p]);
return 0;
}
```

I'm just a little confused when it comes to the (c[b])[p] part in the printf statement.
Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `c[b]` means the same as `*(c + b)`. That should help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @BennoZeeman You forgot some parentheses. They matter. i.e., see the current answer.

Comment: A more compleat explanation is in [With C arrays, why is it the case that a\[5\] == 5\[a\] ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

Comment: @remyabel Thanks, you're correct. I just checked the C standard, they mention that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bit weird to be written that way, but the `[]` operator in C is commutative.  That means `(c[b])[p]` is the same as `p[b[c]]`, which is a lot easier to understand:

```
p[b[c]] = p[b[5]] = p[6] = a[6] = 7
```

Doing the same with the original expression will work too, it's just a bit weird to look at in places:

```
(c[b])[p] = (5[b])[p] = (b[5])[p]) = 6[p] = p[6] = a[6] = 7
```

The commutativity (if that's a word) of `[]` is just due to its definition - that is, `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)`, where you can see the order of `a` and `b` doesn't matter.